# Is this a climber? Any idea what it is?

Tags: identification, pruning, roses

[image][image][image]enter image description here[image]
I inherited this beautiful rose plant when I bought my home.  I live in Florida.  I studied pruning online and thought I did pretty well, but I don't know if I should prune it way back next year during our one (sorta) cold month of January.  I do deadhead and the branches I've cut seem to do very well.  It mostly blooms on the end of very long branches.  Sometimes in groups of five roses and sometimes just one rose.  It blooms over and over.  I'm thinking it's too "leggy" as there aren't many roses in the mid part of the "bush".  What am I doing right?  Wrong?  Oh, also they have a pretty scent, not too strong.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you add a photo showing the plant from the ground up please - want to look at how many stems there are and how tall ....

Comment: Hi:  Sure, I had to hunt for one, sorry!  It is at least 6-7 feet tall.  All branches originate from big "trunk" or "stem".  Sorry, this was my first rose encounter.  I was so afraid it wouldn't live.  Evidently it's been in the yard for a long time!     These aren't perfect, but they're what I have right now.  Thank you for responding!

Comment: I will concentrate on better pruning in January.  And, ill try to support the branches horizontally, as described.  I'm very excited now to see what it will do!  I can see a comment in my inbox from Bamboo but when I click on it, it takes me only to the answer left by @33232.  Was that other one deleted?  I'm BRAND new to this so I may have done something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this a climber this is what you should do:

If you only have flowers at the top, then pruning is the issue.

It should be done in the dormant season, January is best on a cold but dry day.

The idea of a climber is to create a woody frame first of multiple branches And have that frame as horizontal as possible and attach it to wires to give it support. Like tree branches without a trunk!

What this will do is push the plant to grow side shoots which will be vertical, basically looking for the sun... this is where your flowers will be.

In winter, you prune the rose and “trick it” in thinking it is being weakened. The response is for lots of its energy to make flowers in order to seed and survive.

The pruning is done on the vertical side shoots, leaving 2 buds on it. 
Take out dead, damage, diseased branches first. 
Using these techniques, learn to improve the shape and flower production of the plant.

Good luck.

[image]

[image]

If this is a  Floribunda or a Hybrid tea, the pruning is similar. See below

[image]